# MySQL Fulltext search: How do I match a string with a minus char?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `ftx_utf8` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `col2` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `FTX` (`col1`,`col2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

with the content

```
|id|col1   |col2   |
|1 |255-381|       |
|2 |       |255-381|
|3 |255381 |       |
|4 |       |255381 |
```

Now If I execute the query:

```
SELECT id, MATCH(col1, col2) AGAINST ('"255381"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS match1
FROM ftx_utf8
HAVING match1 > 0
```

it returns rows 3 and 4

But this query

```
SELECT id, MATCH(col1, col2) AGAINST ('"255-381"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS match1
FROM ftx_utf8
HAVING match1 > 0
```

does not return rows 1 and 2 as expected.
How can I match `255-381` with MySQL Fulltext search?

The odd thing is that a customer claims it worked before.
But last week we did an update of his database from an early 5.0 installation to a 5.1.54 server (Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixes the problem. Or at least I know what is happening:

MySQL ignores certain keywords in his fulltext index. If you have a column containing `255-381`, mysql stores `255` and `381` in his full text index as single words. Or to be more precise, by default, these two values are even ignored because the minimum word length, specified by `ft_min_word_len=?` is 4. But if you set the value to `3` and serch for `255-381` the fulltext search engine searches for the exact phrase `"255 381"` and returns the row containing `255-381` because `255` followed by `381` is stored in the index.

That works for the example provided in the initial question but is not a perfect solution, because it does not apply for values with 2 chars or even one char followed by a minus.
Let's assume I want to search for `25-5381`. `25` is skipped because it is shorter than the `ft_min_word_len` threshold. So a search for `25-5381` is basically the same as a search for `5381` which would also return the rows containing `26-5381` `5381` and `5381-12`

Since I don't have the time to switch to a better full text search engine like sphynx or lucene and a `LIKE` query would be to slow, I suppose I will use a workaround:

I will add another column containing all entries from col1 and col2 but replace "-" chars with special string like `MINUS` and will perform a fulltext query on that column with `255MINUS381` which should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but, did u try with REGEX (Regular Expressions) instead? And... why do u use double quotes? Just ' or ", not both. Even more, why you use text and varchar? I think you come from other SQL language, try just MySQL

Comment: Quotes are used to match an exact phrase.

Comment: By default mysql searchs by exact phrase against you specify some kind of wildcard like %. Did you change it?

Comment: Nope. `MATCH...AGAINST` clause requires quotes for exact matching (at least by default). I really don't know if it's possible to change this behaviour because I never needed it :)

Comment: There's some problems with 5.1 that they re not fixed yet, i've some issues relationated with UDF so i've to back to 5.0, i think this is the most stable version. But anyway, i dont think that the problem come with the updating of the server. Instead, i still believe that its a collation problem, there are the same? Again, as expected, varchar and text type, have -not- the same behavior and of course, any problem of these mentioned before, you can solve it with REGEX. Give it a chance, its a good fix and must be work. If you do it, forget about binary comparision.

Comment: The customer wants to search his system for item codes of spare parts. Let's say he has a product with item code `123-456` that is also available from other vendors under a different code. The products are imported and the original data has a item code (col1) and a multiline text field with the product description (col2) that contains the additional item codes. If someone asks for item `123-456` our customer wants to search his database for the item code itself and for items that have this code in the description. Hope that clarifies the situation. I addd an answer with updates.

Answer (score 0):

Just find nice way to do this.

```
SELECT (
 MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('+$keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) + (`name`=$keyword)*2 
) as `rel`
```